# Configure and host asp.net website on VPS Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, hosting, configure, vps

It's the first time that I owned a VPS server(provider is constant.com).

I have googled out about it but no luck and not sure how to configure and host asp.net website.

I've worked on my website for a while and now it's time to let it go for online test. I have a VPS and a domain.

I am familiar with cPanel but constan's support team says that cPanel not supported on windows os server. Is that normal?

Therefore, I need to connect remotely through Remote Desktop.

1. Do i need to install Visual Studio and MS SQL Server on VPS? If so, how's it possible?
2. Can i install cPanel on windows based VPs server?
3. What i need to do to configure and host my website with my owned domain on virtual server?

Any guides and suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You dont need to install Visual Studio unless you are planning to code on it. You can still use your local installation and upload updates from there. If your project needs SQL then you should install it on the VPS. As an option you can use dedicated SQL hosting at additional cost or Windows Azure SQL.
2. Yes you can install cPanel or such if cPanel not supported (like anything else) but I dont think you need. Thechnicaly a VPS allows you to do same things you can do on any phisical server. And your hoster gives you local admin rights. So you dont need any hosting panels in addition to OS tools you already have.
3. It is very depends from what your project needs. You might need to configure IIS server on that VPS. You need to setup DNS record to allow users to use domain name instead of IP (use your domain registrar panel). You also might want to install [Microsoft Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) which will help you to deploy your project directly from VisualStudio. If you plan to use SSL, you will need to get a cert and install on your VPS and setup IIS to work with.
   There is nothing super special than you wont be able to do. So congrats with your first VPS and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response. You said, "You need to setup DNS record to allow users to use domain name instead of IP (use your domain registrar panel)", How to manage and configure to use domain name instead ip?

Comment: You need to do it on your domain registrar. Every registrar has a control panel where you can manage registered domains. Find out what are your VPS Name Servers (within your hoster, find this info on his web site). Go to domain registrar's control panel and assign these names to your domain name. I'm sorry but I can't give you exact scenario since every registrar has own way how make this done. Look for "Nameservers" as a key word. You need to specify at least two name servers. That's basically it. Now your customers will be redirected to your server by your domain name.

Comment: I have found that within DNS panel. It asks me to give `domain name` and `ip v4 address`. From where i am can find my domain `ip v4 address`(it may be through whois, right?). And name servers for my VPs are `ns1.constant.com` and `ns2.constant.com`.

Comment: thanks, i got it and now it's active. Now my vps points to my new domain. One last question can i setup or configure multiple domains for multiple websites(multiple in the sense domain per each website) on VPS? Your help really helpful to me to host my site on my first VPS. :)

Comment: You need to ask your hoster support about the IP. It could be on confirmation e-mail when you bought your VPS. If you won't find, ask support "What is my VPS's static IP?". Whois won't return right IP until you assign it to your domain name.

Comment: To support multiple domains you will need to get multiple static IP addresses. Hosters usually take some setup + monthly fees for them. Then on your VPS you will need to create new sites in IIS, assign new IPs to them and then repeat same actions on registrar as you did for first domain. I'm glad to help you!